# Grouping in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I got the the xml like this

```
<feature ufi="-1578440">
    <designation>PPLA</designation>  
    <administrative_division>06</administrative_division>
    <name_type>V</name_type>
    <full_name>Hobart Town</full_name>
    <sort_key>HOBARTTOWN</sort_key>
    <modified>2012-02-06</modified>
</feature>
<feature ufi="-1578440">
    <designation>PPLA</designation>
    <administrative_division>06</administrative_division>
    <name_type>N</name_type>
    <full_name>Hobart</full_name>
    <sort_key>HOBART</sort_key>
    <modified>2012-02-06</modified>
</feature>
```

Basically, the information of 2 fields is similar except the name_type. So I would like to generate the output something like this using xsl grouping.

```
Hobart (also known as Hobart Town), PPLA, V, 2012-02-06
```

Could anyone suggest me the simple way to achieve the result. Thanks a lot

Edit: I suppose to do that with xsl version 1 with key is ufi

Comment: Do you want plain text output as the XSLT transformation result? Do you use XSLT 1.0 or 2.0? And what is the grouping key, is that the `ufi` attribute value?

Comment: Does it matter which of the `<feature>` elements is chosen to define the basic name and which are "also known as" names? And is the `<name_type>` field of any consequence here?

Answer (score 1):

No grouping involved, but this will get the job done (assuming plain text output and disregarding newline stuff, left as an exercise):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="feature[name_type='N']">
        <xsl:value-of select="full_name"/>
        <xsl:variable name="ufi" select="@ufi"/>
        (also known as <xsl:value-of select="../feature[name_type='V' and @ufi=$ufi]/full_name"/>)
        , <xsl:value-of select="designation"/>, <xsl:value-of select="name_type"/>, <xsl:value-of select="modified"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="feature"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

using xslt 2.0 would be much much nicer though..